# How Update a data from an object of json type column in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, object

I have an object of json type column in my table (properties) in MySQL like:

```
[
    {
        "unit": "2",
        "floor": "1",
        "price": "6000000",
        "toilet": "2",
        "balcony": "2",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "customer": "3",
        "bathrooms": "3",
        "flat_name": "1A",
        "flat_size": "1200",
        "floor_plan": "217",
        "price_per_sqft": "5000"
    },
    {
        "unit": "2",
        "floor": "1",
        "price": "5000000",
        "toilet": "2",
        "balcony": "2",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "customer": null,
        "bathrooms": "3",
        "flat_name": "1B",
        "flat_size": "1200",
        "floor_plan": "215",
        "price_per_sqft": "5000"
    },
    {
        "unit": "1",
        "floor": "2",
        "price": "6000000",
        "toilet": "2",
        "balcony": "2",
        "bedrooms": "2",
        "customer": null,
        "bathrooms": "3",
        "flat_name": "2A",
        "flat_size": "1250",
        "floor_plan": "216",
        "price_per_sqft": "5300"
    }
]
```

How can I update customer id, where flat_name = 1B from this object in Laravel?

Comment: What database are you using - is it postgres? Can you share the table schema so that things are more clearer to people? you can run `DESCRIBE tablename` to do so

Comment: The table name is not essential, this is MySQL, and I have tagged it. You can find

Comment: Can you check https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#updating-json-columns? Its been many years since I used laravel.. But can you check if 
`DB::table('properties')->where('json_column->flat_name' => '1B')->update(['customer_id', 1]);` works?

Comment: This will not work, cause there are multiple flat_name with multiple object

Comment: Do share your table schema please.

Comment: If you are good enough then why you need schema?

Answer (score 0):

I have made the solution with using loop. Thank you who reply and answer

```
$objectitem=Property::where("id", 1)->first();
$updatedFlatDetails= $objectitem->flat_details;

foreach ($objectitem->flat_details as $key => $singleflat){
    if($singleflat['flat_name']==$item->flat_name){
        $updatedFlatDetails[$key]['customer']=(string)$item->customer_id;
    }
}

$objectitem->flat_details = $updatedFlatDetails;
$objectitem->save();
```

Answer (score -3):

Use collection after fetch data from database :

```
$target= $collection->filter(function ($item) {
    return $item->flat_name=="1B";
})->values();
```

or filter before fetch data use eloquent :

```
Model::where('flat_name','1B')->get();
```

Comment: do you understand, what I need?

Comment: you can select and update special row and filter by property right ?

Comment: hey ahmad, can you answer the question instead of making the questioner think about how to solve it on his own?